# 100% apache cpu usage after upgrade

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

Greetings,

I run LAMP on an Ubuntu 8.04 server. I recently completed a "sudo apt-get upgrade" and upgraded all components found.

After this, my Apache frequently uses way too much cpu which in turn causes the website its running to become inaccessible. Before the upgrade it never exceeded around 2-3%.

Doing a "sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart" does not restart Apache, it has to be killed using "killall apache".

I am running

```
PHP 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.7 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Aug 21 2009 19:52:39)
Copyright (c) 1997-2007 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2007 Zend Technologies

Server version: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Aug 18 2009 14:18:10
```

Here is a screenshot taken of "htop": http://bayimg.com/image/hadoeaack.jpg

And here is one of "munin": bayimg.com/image/hadobaack.jpg

I would be eternally grateful for any help as I am loosing users by the minute! Thank you!

Edit: Maybe there is some correlation here:

```
1144 [Wed Sep 02 03:29:11 2009] [error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
1145 [Wed Sep 02 10:07:48 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
1146 [Wed Sep 02 10:08:22 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations

-------------------

1162 [Wed Sep 02 16:10:14 2009] [error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
1163 [Wed Sep 02 19:03:53 2009] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
1164 [Wed Sep 02 19:04:13 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
1165 [Wed Sep 02 19:05:52 2009] [error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
```

But reaching MaxClients should not cause Apache to crash...? Surely?

Comment: You should read this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/prefork.html

Comment: Also, can you post the output of "free -m"?

Comment: *Reading*

"free -m":
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2017       1865        152          0        121       1520
-/+ buffers/cache:        222       1794
Swap:         5906          0       5906

Comment: "free -m": http://bayimg.com/image/ladogaack.jpg

Comment: munin memory log: http://bayimg.com/image/madocaack.jpg

Comment: the irregular fork rate corresponds to our problems: http://bayimg.com/image/madoiaack.jpg

Comment: I read the link you posted Karolis T., and understand the basic concept, however I am sadly none the wiser at how to solve my problem! Our interrupts are normally quite steady, but have been going bananas since around the crashes: http://bayimg.com/image/oadoaaack.jpg

Comment: You don't mention what web application you were running, but since list mod_wsgi in module list, you perhaps should ensure you read 'http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html'.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving it this way:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep apache
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep php
```

to find all of the apache/php packages, and then

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-mpm-worker apache2-threaded-dev apache2-utils apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-python-doc libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

to completely remove them.

Then reinstalled the same packages using

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-mpm-worker apache2-threaded-dev apache2-utils apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-python-doc libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

This gives you a completely fresh install of Apache and PHP.

Thanks to http://dancingpenguinsoflight.com/2009/02/how-to-completely-reset-an-apache-instance-in-ubuntu/